# How to bind value from nested json to ng-model dynamically in angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I'm currently working on angularjs project and since I'm a fresher, I have doubt on ng-model directive ... I need to know how to dynamically bind value from nested json to ng-model in the html page ... In below code, I want to bind resumeField value(which is also a json object =>(resume.firstName)) in ng-model. To be simple, the value of firstName in resume json should be assigned as value of resumeField and it should be binded to ng-model in html page. And it should also be editable. That's it. If anyone knows, pls reply with your answers... Thanks in advance ...

This is my html code

```
<section ng-repeat="sec in section">
 <div class="edit-container">
    <div class="conatainer nopadding">
     <div ng-repeat="subSec in sec.subSection">
      <div class="templist">
        <h2 style="width: 100px; color: {{subSec.color}};">{{subSec.label}}</h2>
    <!-- <h1 style="color:#fff;">james</h1> -->
    <div ng-repeat="field in subSec.field">
      <md-input-container md-no-float>
        <input style="width: 100px; color: {{field.colorField}}" type="{{field.type}}" placeholder="{{field.placeHolder}}" ng-model="{{field.resumeField}}"/>
      </md-input-container>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div> 
 </div> 
</div>
```

and this is my json structure

```
{
"name": "sample01",
"section": [
    {
        "position": {
            "x": 100,
            "y": 100
        },
        "subSection": [
            {
                "field": [
                    {
                        "resumeField": "resume.firstName",
                        "placeHolder": "firstName",
                        "type": "text",
                        "colorField": "resume.template.color2",
                        "size": 14
                    },
                    {
                        "resumeField": "resume.lastName",
                        "placeHolder": "lastName",
                        "type": "text",
                        "colorField": "resume.template.color2",
                        "size": 14
                    },
                    {
                        "resumeField": "user.email",
                        "placeHolder": "email",
                        "type": "text",
                        "colorField": "resume.template.color2",
                        "size": 14
                    },
                    {
                        "resumeField": "resume.currentAddress.city",
                        "placeHolder": "city",
                        "type": "text",
                        "colorField": "resume.template.color2",
                        "size": 14
                    },
                    {
                        "resumeField": "resume.currentAddress.state",
                        "placeHolder": "state",
                        "type": "text",
                        "colorField": "resume.template.color2",
                        "size": 14
                    },
                    {
                        "resumeField": "resume.currentAddress.country",
                        "placeHolder": "country",
                        "type": "text",
                        "colorField": "resume.template.color2",
                        "size": 14
                    },
                    {
                        "resumeField": "resume.currentAddress.address1",
                        "placeHolder": "address1",
                        "type": "text",
                        "colorField": "resume.template.color2",
                        "size": 14
                    },
                    {
                        "resumeField": "resume.currentAddress.address2",
                        "placeHolder": "address2",
                        "type": "text",
                        "colorField": "resume.template.color2",
                        "size": 14
                    },
                    {
                        "resumeField": "resume.mobileNo",
                        "placeHolder": "mobileNo",
                        "type": "text",
                        "colorField": "resume.template.color2",
                        "size": 14
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "Education Summary",
                "color": "resume.template.color1",
                "size": 14,
                "field": [
                    {
                        "resumeField": "resume.education",
                        "type": "array",
                        "colorField": "resume.template.color2",
                        "size": 12
                    },
                    {
                        "resumeField": "resume.education.domain",
                        "placeHolder": "domain",
                        "type": "text",
                        "colorField": "resume.template.color2",
                        "size": 12
                    },
                    {
                        "resumeField": "resume.education.specializtion",
                        "placeHolder": "specializtion",
                        "type": "text",
                        "colorField": "resume.template.color2",
                        "size": 12
                    },
                    {
                        "resumeField": "resume.education.from",
                        "placeHolder": "fromDate",
                        "type": "text",
                        "colorField": "resume.template.color2",
                        "size": 12
                    },
                    {
                        "resumeField": "resume.education.to",
                        "placeHolder": "toDate",
                        "type": "text",
                        "colorField": "resume.template.color2",
                        "size": 12
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

This is my controller.js

```
'use strict';
```

var myResume = angular.module('myResume');

```
myResume.controller('resumeController',['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {


    $http({
        url: 'http://192.168.1.14:8000/api/getJson',
        method: 'GET',
        headers:
            {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
    }).success(function(result, status, headers) {
        /*var a = result;
        console.log(a);*/
        $scope.section = result.section;
        /*$scope.details = result.section[0].subSection[0].field;*/

        console.log($scope.section);
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment buddy ... But a small doubt in this ... Will this render the value of resumeField ??? I mean the value will be an another Json value (resume.firstName) ... If you go through the json which i have posted ... You may understand what I am trying to convey ...